# Relations with attributes in a DDD application

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design

I'm currently trying to imagine a DDD PHP application based on a simple domain : a **comment** management, with some **notation** associated. Each comment can be noted by any **registered user**. The thing is I'm having trouble understanding the way I can possibly design that notation feature.

Basically, a note is a value from 0 to 100, originated by a user and related to a particular comment. A way of designing this thing would be to turn it as a relation with attribute between the user entity and the comment entity. **Doctrine2**, for instance, allows me to work with a dedicated entity, with a oneToMany relation towards the user entity, and a oneToMany relation towards the comment entity.

But from my point of view, a note can't really be seen as a proper entity as it doesn't hold any actual functionality, it is just a value with some relations to some other objects. I don't see the point in designing a concrete implementation of this element.

Is designing an actual entity to hold the relation a good practice, or can it be done in some other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Notation is probably a Value Object.

Value Objects - in contrary to Entities - don't have an identity and are immutable.

Yes, you should make explicit what is implicit. It refers to even more primitive ideas, for example you can have an explicit Value Object for Email, not just a string.